# Can we encrypt the entire config file?

Tags: .net, vb.net, app-config

Is it possible to encrypt the whole app.config file rather than encrypting any particular section of the config file using VB.Net ?

Comment: Please review your previously asked questions and mark answers as appropriate - you may find people are more willing to provide answers to your new questions that way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with Cryptography Application Block from Enterprise Library.
[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff632023.aspx)

Max